# AOG Chinese version: Sometimes got Invocation Error? AOG unstable?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I got some error: Invocation Error in AOG last week, shown all of Chinese projects can’t executed and show “Invocation Error “.  I didn’t do any change, all Chinese projects became OK in pass three days.  Now, again I got same errors today, all English version projects are OK, but Chinese projects all FAIL, even a very very small project without any Intent.

> ***Invocation Error**
> You cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator. If you want to try them, use Google Assistant on your phone or other compatible devices.*

This question is regarding to Chinese, perhaps, it’s almost impossible to have replies in an English-based community, that is why I proposed this question to AOG support team again, this is an extremely fundamental question: Does AOG really support Traditional Chinese? If positive, why it is such unstable?

I have wasted two weeks at this issue.  Anyone experienced the AOG Chinese issue? which is, I can trigger the Invocation phase, but any input will induce  **Invocation Error**

Comment: Are you able to amend your post to show a minimal example that a Google Assistant developer could use to replicate your problem?

Comment: In fact, I wrote a very simple one.  Step:1. create a project, select language Traditional Chinese.  Step2: put on one Invocation name, I use ( 電影博士),  without any Intent.  Step3: please perform Simulation Test.  The point is, if u can enter Chinese words, u can verify it.  Supposedly, it works for a while, and sometimes, it response: Invocation Error
You cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator. If you want to try them, use Google Assistant on your phone or other compatible devices.

Answer (score 0):

All of my 4 Chinese AOG projects are back to normal without previous error suddenly, this error happened once in three days ago.  Already issue an email to the AOG team before, they just respond that AOG does support Chinese version.

In fact, all of Chinese projects are all FAIL with “Invocation Error” yesterday, and when I arrived office in this morning, before I revise anything, I perform one Chinese AOG project,it is suddenly OK in this morning, and the rest Chinese AOG projects are all NORMAL now.

Is it very weird?